# File extension for OPUS audio files

Tags: audio

The OPUS audio codec is supported by android. According to [opus-codec.org](http://opus-codec.org/) the recommended file extension is .opus Android does not seem to see .opus files. It only sees opus audio files in an .ogg container and only with .ogg extension. Is it foreseen that android can read .opus files as described in the opus documentation?
Thanks and regards

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: What app are you asking about?

Comment: Some Android audio apps (such as BubbleUPnP or USB Audio Player Pro) have support for opus built in. They can play files with an opus extension. Other apps do not have support for opus (such as the Sony Music App of my Xperia XZ1). It can only play files that android natively supports. As andorid only plays opus files that have an .ogg extension, the Sony music app can only play opus files that have an .ogg extension.

Comment: I was asking whether android will ever natively support opus files with an .opus extension, so that the Sony app may be able to play them.

Comment: Google Play Music can play .opus files, but doesn't index them and don't offer them in its Library (after auto scan).

Comment: Same with Pulsar. Trying all until I find one...

Comment: Same with Musicolet Music Player ..

Comment: foobar2000 does! (Have to force a rescan though!)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foobar2000.foobar2000